# Create blank table from unix shell

Tags: postgis, postgresql, command-line

I am in the middle of trying to create my first PostGiS database and seem to be running into problems developing scripts to automate importing the various spatial formats so I can use them in my analysis.  I am writing today trying to develop a way to batch import shape files into separate tables.  From my research, it looks like i need to have empty tables created before i can batch `shp2pgsql` command from postgis.  In an effort to make this question tractable and leave some learning for myself, I am trying to create empty tables in my database using the structure from a table named `test` in my PostgreSQL database from a unix shell.  Here is script I have been developing:

```
#!/bin/sh

for FILE in c:/workspace/CM/mb_sed_class/output2/*.shp
do

   echo $FILE
   filename="${FILE##*/}"
   nakedname="${filename%.shp}"
   (cd C:/Program\ Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin; psql -h localhost -d mb_sed_class -U postgres -v name='&nakedname' -c "CREATE TABLE name AS SELECT * FROM test WHERE 1=2;")

done
```

This script creates a table named 'name' and isn't passing the variable into the sql statement.  Any ideas  on how to pass a variable from the shell to a sql statement?

Comment: Multi-line input like this probably doesn't work on Windows with cmd.exe, especially in a subshell. On unix you'd use a here document. I don't know what the cmd.exe alternative is, maybe a tempfile.

Comment: In the process of clarifying my question, I found the solution to my question.  To pass a variable from the shell to a sql statement I did not need to use the `-v name=` flag, I just needed to change `"CREATE TABLE name...."` to `"CREATE TABLE "$nakedname"..."`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The psql option for executing sql commands is `-c` and not `-e`. The -e option means (from the psql help):

> -e, --echo-queries       echo commands sent to server

Because the -e option does not take arguments, your sql command is simply ignored.

What you need is:

> -c, --command=COMMAND    run only single command (SQL or internal) and exit

Also,this should work:

```
psql -h localhost -d mb_sed_class -U postgres -c 'CREATE TABLE "Segment_029_2009_x_y_sedclass_dt_topo_25cm" ...........'
```

For more infos:

```
psql --help
```

PS: I'm not working on windows, but I don't think you need to navigate to the bin directory to execute psql. Try removing this from code:

```
cd C:/Program\ Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was off my game yesterday and did not ask a very tractable question.  I agree with changing the `-e` flag to a `-c` flag to run a sql statement.  Also I am I found if i add `c:\program files\postgresql\9.4\bin\psql.exe` to my system environment path I done need to temporarily change directories to use the `psql` command.

Comment: BTW, shp2pgsql should **not** need empty tables created in advance. It just outputs the full SQL commands for creating and populating spatial tables, to be piped into pgsql.